# WSO2 Greg Property Handler

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I need to copy a resource collection to another

**`Registry.copy`** method works perfectly for this

Now I've to implement a kind of merge and i'm dealing with this constraint :

> Only the new properties must be copied from source to target

Is it possible handle this condition using **`Handler`** ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do this using a handler. please refer below sample media type handlers available in greg(carbon-registry)

[WSDLMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/WSDLMediaTypeHandler.java)

[SwaggerMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/SwaggerMediaTypeHandler.java)

[WADLMediaTypeHandler.java](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-registry/blob/7a7ef5b9998bd46f5be3fd2684951991bfc51386/components/registry/org.wso2.carbon.registry.extensions/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/registry/extensions/handlers/WADLMediaTypeHandler.java)

Please find [this useful article](http://sencs.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-develop-governance-registry.html) which will teach you how to create a simple handler.